# What is the phrase used to convey the meaning of "to clock in and to clock out"?

Tags: word-choice

Recently most big companies use digital attendance systems to keep track of their employee attendance.

Employees must clock in before starting working and clock out at the end. Is there a special English phrase to convey the meaning of the procedure of "clock in and clock out"?

More precisely, what is the special phrase to fill in the following blank space?

> In order to keep track employee attendance, the company prompts employees to ____________ on weekdays.

## Edit:

For the sake of generality, the phrase I am looking for is something like "to declare attendance".

Comment: It's not exactly a common usage, but you'd be understood by any native speaker if you "verbify" the noun: *In order to track employee attendance, the company requires employees to **timeclock** on weekdays*. Or just *...to **clock/sign in***, since it's contextually obvious anyone doing that would also *clock/sign **out*** every day as well.

Comment: What's wrong with "clock in and clock out"? It would be widely understood in English.

Comment: @AndyT: No problem with that phrase actually. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider, ***punch the clock***

> 1. to record on a special clock when you arrive and leave work e.g. "In our factory, if you don't punch a clock, you don't get paid"
> 2. to go to work every day e.g. "One I retire I won't have to punch the clock every day"
>
> [Idiomhq](http://www.idiomhq.com/phrases/punch-the-time-clock#.VtBkiIe9KSN)
>
> 1. To register one's arrive or departure at a job.
> 2. To be employed at a job with regular hours.
>
> [FOD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/punch+the+time+clock)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=punch+the+clock&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpunch%20the%20clock%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

Note that you should say either "In order to track employee attendance..." **or** "In order to keep track **of** employee attendance...".

I would simply say:

*In order to track employee attendance, the company prompts employees to clock in and out on weekdays.*

or perhaps "sign" instead:

*In order to track employee attendance, the company prompts employees to sign in and out on weekdays.*

In both cases the language is a little outdated:  they are not putting cards in a clock which stamps them (like people used to) and they're not actually signing anything either.  But the language persists because they  are effectively performing the same function.

For a more up-to-date version, you could say "swipe" instead of "sign" or "clock", reflecting the fact that it is usually done by swiping a card across or near a card reader, and the verb "swipe" has become synonymous with the process of presenting a card to a card-reading device.

Comment: How about the case in which we must put our fingers on a bio-metric scanner?

Comment: I would probably just stick with "sign" to cover all actual physical means of doing it.  I think it would be acceptable to write *"In order to track employee attendance, the company prompts employees to sign in and out on weekdays, using a fingerprint scanner."*  Everyone would understand what was meant by this, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider to *swipe* or *tag* their (employment) cards. Nowadays, their clock-in and clock-out times are automatically recorded when they just [swipe](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/swipe) or [tag](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tag) thier cards.

> In order to keep track of employee attendance, the company requests
>   employees to swipe or tag their cards on weekdays.